# How to extract expressions '$%&*@ ' in a particular part of a text? i.e. after numerical values or before

Tags: mysql, sql

I am completely new to SQL but my new job requires me to learn as I go. I work of an e-commerce website with an inventory of over 100,000 types of product.

Often the descripion and titles vendors upload contain some sort of formating error; `'Power drill& 12V? without battery'`.

My job is to try and extract all product titles and descriptions that contain these formatting errors for our review and improvement.

I've figured out the code to find titles/descriptions that contain some of these expressions. My issues is that some titles contain '`$`' in places where it doesn't make sense; '`Hedge trimmer$ black full length`'.

Is there a function or expression I could use to locate `$` that are not near numerical values (indicating price)?

I hope I was clear in my explanation. Many thanks!

```
select id, name_product, description
from dim_product_current
where platform_id={{platform_id}}
  and name_product Like '%$%'
```

This is the code i've built thus far. I have no coding experience so I wouldnt even know where to start.

Comment: Consider researching FULL TEXT indexes and FULL text searching https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html instead .. As `Like '%$%'` will not run fast on larger tables..

Comment: ... but you need to use [REGEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) after those results you search with the full text search to futher check -> *"How to extract expressions '$%&*@ ' in a particular part of a text? i.e. after numerical values or before"* .. The full text searching is meant to make a smaller search window as REGEX in MySQL can not use indexes aswell..   Also research how to write derived tables In MySQL as you need that

Comment: ... but see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) then we can help better..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you, I will definitely take look into it!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to workaround regexp as below sample

```
     Select 
        REGEXP_REPLACE('%^[0- 
         9]^[$&*%]^[0-9]%', '')  from 
      table
      Where REGEXP '%^[0-9]^[$&*%]^[0- 
         9]%' and not like '
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a regular expression search.  I entered *mysql regular expression* in the search bar of my browser.  The first link returned seems to have some good information.  Which specific function you need will depend on your full requirement.

Probably something like...

```
select id
, name_product
, description
from dim_product_current
where platform_id={{platform_id}} 
  and name_product REGEXP '.*\\$[^0-9].*'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html
https://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html